# Unable to import youtubeplayerapi.jar

Tags: android, jar

I have implemented playing youtube video using youtubeplayer fragment.When I have implemented the code at that time location of youtubeplayer api.jar was in D:\ drive. I have changed the location of jar file.Now its in `D:\folder`.I have imported the jar file again by following these steps:

1. Copy the jar file from libs folder to the the libs folder of your project.
2. Right click on your project, Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries Tab
3. Add Jars -> Select Your project’s libs folder -> Select YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI.jar ->Ok
4. Order and Export Tab -> Check YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI.jar – Ok

But when I am going on 3 step ok button is not getting enabled. 
I have also changed the location of jar file again to `D:\` but didnt get any any success.

How can this problem of mine can be resolved?Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: on 2nd step goto your jar file in your project -->right click buildpath--> add to buildpath

Comment: @raj-not getting the option of add to buildpath..getting only 2 options if I follow your step.Options that I am getting are-1.Use as source folder 2. Configure build path

Comment: ok go to configure build path--> order and export and right check your jar. and start using it

Comment: @raj- I dont know why but I am not getting my jar file directly in order and export tab.

Comment: you are doing wrong steps

Comment: first step is fine in second step go to libs folder and right click on jar file insted of right click on project-->build path -->add to build path

Comment: then youll find your jar in order and export tab

Comment: @raj-none of your solution is working.

Comment: this is because you are doing it wrong way

Comment: give me your team viewer id at info@pairdroid.com

Answer (score 0):

step 1:- copy the jar file in libs folder ->YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI.jar

Step 2:-right click the libs folder : libs->Build path ->Configure Build path

Note there are 2 option when you click ,Build path :libs->Build path ->Use Source folder and  libs->Build path ->Configure Build path .

you should follow this path :-libs->Build path ->Configure Build path

Step 3:- then libraries tab : Click Add Jars Button on Right side,then select the libs folder of your project .In the libs folder click the jar file. Then click ok.Now you can see the jar file in libraries tab .

Step 4:-Click Order & Export tab :check the jar file,click ok..

Before following these steps note that you should delete the jar file that you already copied and start to import once again

refer this link:-  http://android-er.blogspot.de/2013/06/download-and-import-youtube-android.html

Comment: @user3173628-I have followed till adding jar file of my project but still ok button is not enabled.

Comment: @user3173628-i have already followed the link provided by you.I have to copy the unzipped file in libs folder??

Comment: yes ,you should unzip the jar file and copy the jar file in libs folder

Comment: @user3173628-I have copied the unzipped file in libs folder.

Comment: okey then you try these steps.let me know whether itz working

Comment: @user3173628-yes I have tried steps as mentioned by you but I stuck while adding jar file of my project in libraries tab.When I add jar file ok button is not getting enabled.

Comment: can you post the screenshot of Libraries tab & order and export

Comment: @user3173628-I am trying to attach image here but not able to do it.Can u share ur mail id so that I cn send u over there?

Comment: sorry . but sure I will guide you donot worry

Comment: @user3173628-I am saving the image using printscreen.Is there any other way to save the image because I think we can take the screenshot of image of our emulator.

Comment: I cannot give you my email id so leave that...now my question is: I think you are facing the problem in click ok button. click add jar button, So can explain what you did after clicking the Add jar button

Comment: @NehaAgarwal you can try another way .Project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path then click Add external jar so open the jar file from your computer may be this one will work

Comment: @user3173628-after that i click on my project and then on libs folder and then on jar file

Comment: @user3173628-I have tried that another way.I have successfully imported jar file but I am getting errors in my activity since I am not getting any option to import YouTubeBaseActivity,YouTubePlayerFragment and all.

Comment: @NehaAgarwal  delete the jar file from libs folder ,then can you try like this Project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path then click Add external jar    ,then select the jar file from your computer.

Comment: @user3173628-tried this way but getting errors in my activity since it is not showing any options for import

Comment: @NehaAgarwal                                                      I think importing jar file problem is solved ..so now the problem is in code try to add these lines in your code after package line on the top ,,,,, import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity; import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult; import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer; import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment; import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView; import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;